# SQL Server - Backup/Restore or rollback with functional tests commiting transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a bunch of functional tests that I'm transitioning from H2 to SQL Server. In between running some tests, I would (automatically) backup the database, drop everything from the database, and restore the database all using SQL.

Backup/Restore with SQL Server is not working using the standard BACKUP DATABASE and RESTORE DATABASE commands, because in order to restore, I need to call `ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`, which kills the connection between the test server and the database.

I would like to create a save point and then rollback to it, but the rollback doesn't work, I'm assuming because transactions in the APIs are committing in between the creation of the save point and the rollback. I'm setting autocommit to false in the functional test code, and I'm not getting any autocommit errors.

One idea would be to restore using SQL by dropping all the tables and restoring them. I'm not sure how to go about that, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: In SQL Server, right click on the database name, go to Tasks, then Generate Scripts. The wizard will walk you through how to script out a table schema along with every row in the table at the moment. Perhaps you could automate that piece and then whenever you wanted, you could script the schema and data, drop the table, and then recreate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to backup a database without killing connections. You can also restore the DB to a different name, this would allow you to do testing and not kill the connections.

As for backing up and automated restore, this has been publicly scripted already.

[Backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

[Automated restore](http://www.codepimp.org/2015/04/automated-restore-using-ola-hallengrens-sql-server-backup/)

Comment: Alas, no. The restore attempts to take a database lock which it cannot obtain if there a) active connections that have their database context set to said database or b) any active transactions against said database. I've run into it more times than I can count. You have to take explicit action to kill the above and the `alter database…` method that the OP listed is one that I employ (though I do `alter database [foo] set offline with rollback immediate;` as I've been burned by `single_user` before (specifically, some other transaction getting into the database before I do and locking me out).

Comment: Good info, did some double check reading and edited post. Sounds to me like OP will need something that can handle doing a backup to restore and then kick something else off to establish a new connection to the server after the restore has been finished. (Due to the session being forced disconnected by a method from OP prior to restore.)

Comment: I ended up using backup/restore along with re-establishing the connection.